# Capistrano configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm having some issues with variable scope with the capistrano-ext gem's multistage module. I currently have, in `config/deploy/staging.rb`.

```
set(:settings) { YAML.load_file("config/deploy.yml")['staging'] }

set :repository,  settings["repository"]
set :deploy_to,   settings["deploy_to"]
set :branch,      settings["branch"]
set :domain,      settings["domain"]
set :user,        settings["user"]

role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true
```

My `config/deploy/production.rb` file is similar. This doesn't seem very DRY. Ideally, I think I'd like everything to be in the deploy.rb file. If there were a variable set with the current stage, everything would be really clean.

**UPDATE:** I found a solution.

I defined this function in `deploy.rb`:

```
def set_settings(params)
  params.each_pair do |k,v|
    set k.to_sym, v
  end
  if exists? :domain
    role :app, domain
    role :web, domain
    role :db,  domain, :primary => true
  end
end
```

Then my `staging.rb` file is just `set_settings(YAML.load_file("config/deploy.yml")['staging'])`

Answer (score 2):

You're making this overly complicated.

Just put your common code into your deploy.rb file:

```
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true
```

and your stage-dependent settings in your config/deploy/staging.rb, production.rb, etc. files.

Then run cap  deploy, like you said: cap staging deploy

Your stage.rb files can use common variables as well.  For example, my staging file just has one line:

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{domain}_staging"

The rest is in deploy.rb

Answer (score 0):

try `CAPDEV='staging' cap deploy` and `ENV['CAPDEV']` in deploy.rb

Comment: There's no way to be able to just type `$ cap staging deploy` and have things work?

Answer (score 0):

Eli,

Yes you can do cap staging deploy. Do this at the top of your deploy file.

```
set :deploy_env,  ARGV[0].to_sym
```

or without the symbol if you prefer. But note that this might mandate an environment for simple things like running

```
cap -vT
```